# Background task expiration handler and NSOperationQueue (do we need to wait for operations to finish?)

Tags: ios, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue, background-task

When the expiration handler gets called (synchronously on the main thread) we have to finish up / cancel our task quickly to prevent the app from being terminated.

I read somewhere (but can't find the reference) that all processing must have completely finished by the time the expiration block returns.

Does that mean, if I'm using an NSOperationQueue, that I have to cancel and then wait for the operations to finish before returning? Like this:

```
backgroundTaskIdentifier = UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithName("MyBackgroundTask") {
    operationQueue.cancelAllOperations()
    operationQueue.waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished() // Wait, so everything finishes before returning from this func (but might deadlock!)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(backgroundTaskIdentifier)
}
```

This means locking the main thread, which could cause some tasks that require the background thread to deadlock.

NSOperation's that get cancelled might need a small amount of time (maybe even a second or two) to properly cancel, so how can we ever *safely* be sure that it's really finished by the time the expiration handler is called, without accidently deadlocking?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `operationQueue.waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished()` on the main thread it will be blocked, and delegates or other code scheduled from other threads onto the main thread will cause a deadlock.

This is one of the rare cases where you have to "busy wait" and poll (thread-safe!) some sort of flag which indicates that a task has been completed. Fortunately, you can leverage a `RunLoop` without stressing the CPU too much. With a run loop doing the "wait" on the main thread you can also actually execute delegates or continuations scheduled on the main thread without running into a deadlock.

The following code (using Swift) shows how you can use a run loop to accomplish the "busy wait" on the main thread and also a task which executes on the *main thread* as well:

Suppose you have some "future" which represents the eventual result of an asynchronous task:

```
public protocol Future : class {        
    var isCompleted: Bool { get }
    func onComplete(f: ()->())        
}
```

Ideally, you can "register" (one or more) completion handler(s) which get invoked when the future completes.

Now we can define a method `runloopWait` for the future which "waits" on a thread (which must have a RunLoop) up until the future is completed:

```
extension Future {

    public func runLoopWait() {
        // The current thread MUST have a run loop and at least one event source!
        // This is difficult to verfy in this method - thus this is simply
        // a prerequisite which must be ensured by the client. If there is no
        // event source, the run lopp may quickly return with the effect that the
        // while loop will "busy wait".

        var context = CFRunLoopSourceContext()
        let runLoop = CFRunLoopGetCurrent()
        let runLoopSource = CFRunLoopSourceCreate(nil, 0, &context)

        CFRunLoopAddSource(runLoop, runLoopSource, kCFRunLoopDefaultMode)
        self.onComplete() {
            CFRunLoopStop(runLoop);
        }

        while !self.isCompleted {
            CFRunLoopRun()
        }

        CFRunLoopRemoveSource(runLoop, runLoopSource, kCFRunLoopDefaultMode)
    }

}
```

With this code, the run loop only ever returns when the completion handler has been invoked. That is, you actually don't have to *busy* wait, rather it's some sort of *async* wait.

The code below completes the sample with mocking the future and which you can run to examine the solution above. Note, that the implementation of the future is not thread-safe, but should work in this example.

```
public class Task : Future {

    var _completed = false

    let _task: () -> ()
    var _continuation: ()->()

    public init(task: () -> ()) {
        _task = task
        _continuation = {}
    }

    public var isCompleted: Bool {
        return _completed
    }

    public static func start(t: Task, queue: dispatch_queue_t ) {
        dispatch_async(queue) {
            t._task()
            t._completed = true
            t._continuation()
        }
    }

    public func onComplete(f:()->()) {
        _continuation = f
    }

}



let t = Task() {

    for _ in 0...5 {
        sleep(1)
        print(".", terminator: "")
    }
    print("")
}

// run the task on the main queue:
Task.start(t, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())

t.runLoopWait() // "wait" on the main queue
print("main thread finished")
```